# Third person verbs are always conjugated?

Tags: grammar, verbs, american-english, third-person-singular

Sometimes I see third person verbs , though they're not conjugated. Examples:

> I fell my sorrow *Fly* away;
>
> enter This makes my blood *Boil*;

Or, they aren't really verbs? Plz help me.

Answer (score 2):

These are verbs but they are not the third person singular indicative present tense.

Instead, they are "bare infinitives" the infinitive form of the verb without a "to". The infinitive functions a little like a noun.

Some verbs can have an infinitive phrase:

> I ordered him *to wash*.

For some verbs this is a "to infinitive" but for others it is a bare infinitive

> I made him *wash*

But in both cases the verb has its base form (which for most verbs is the same as the first person present tense) But notice with the verb "be/am/is/are" the infinitive "be" is clearly different.

> I made him be good.